# Function becomes case-sensitive on a different server

Tags: mysql, regex, configuration, collation, case-sensitive

I have created the below function in mysql:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fn_header_uploader_address(v_add varchar(500)) RETURNS bigint(20)
begin
DECLARE v_error bigint default 0;

    IF length(v_add) > 100 then
        set v_error = 110;  
    elseif v_add is null or v_add ='' then 
        set v_error=110;
    elseif v_add NOT REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$' then
        set v_error=110;
    end if;   
return v_error;

end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If I run it on local (deterministic/no deterministic clause) , it returns zero (valid email) for the below statement:

```
select fn_header_uploader_address('hello@gmail.com');
```

but on moving the function to a new server, this become case sensitive !!
So now

```
select fn_header_uploader_address('hello@gmail.com'); ---- error 110
```

Any help please ?

Edit:

I have already compared the servers using the below commands:

```
show collation where collation like '%_c%' ;
show variables like '%version%';
```

Comment: Can you use `UPPER(v_add) NOT REGEXP '^[A- ...` to force case; Try checking collation with `SHOW CHARACTER SET`.

Comment: thanks for your reply harvey. I can use upper(v_add), but i am new to mysql. So, I wanted to understand why am i getting different results in 2 different servers.

Comment: thanks harvey, even though your answer solved my problem, i am not able to mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
...
elseif v_add NOT REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$' then
...
```

or binary:

```
...
elseif v_add NOT REGEXP '^[\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a\x30-\x39\x2e\x2d\x5f\x25]+\x40[\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a\x30-\x39\x2e\x2d]+\x2e[\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a]{2,4}$' then
...
```

Comment: I added binary variant of search. It should work anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Ruben. I have tried the regex you mentioned above. But it fails to reject the rows of the below format. The regex accepts rows even when there is '.com' at the end.               select 'tammy@dotcom' not regexp '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$' ;                                                  I have to try and make the 'dot' mandatory in the regex after the '@'